# Displaying a message from managed bean with primefaces confirmation dialog component

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, primefaces

in my page , i'm trying to display a confirmation dialog  after clicking a button .In the confirmation dialog i used the attribute message to display it , this message is taken value after clicking the button . So i did it like that :

```
 <p:commandButton value="Delete" update="testPlanetree" id="deleteBtn" 
   disabled="#{projectTestManagementMB.disable}" oncomplete="deleteConfirmation.show()"
    action="#{projectTestManagementMB.testFn}"/>


 <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="# 
  {projectTestManagementMB.deleteConfirmationMsg}"  
    header="Confirming Deleting Process" severity="alert" 
   widgetVar="deleteConfirmation">  

    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" update="messages"   
     oncomplete="deleteConfirmation.hide()"    />  

      <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" 
       onclick="deleteConfirmation.hide()" type="button" />   

     </p:confirmDialog>
```

ProjectTestManagementMB Managed Bean :

```
    private String deleteConfirmationMsg;//with getters and setters 
    public void testFn(){
       deleteConfirmationMsg="do you want to delete ...";
    }
```

The problem is that the `deleteConfirmationMsg`  never take the value "do you want to delete ..." (is always empty)

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Make sure your setter is exactly like 'setDeleteConfirmationMsg' case-sensitive

Comment: @D3mon: Why would a wrong setter name cause exactly this problem? Even more, is a setter actually mandatory in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<p:confirmDialog>` has already generated its HTML representation on the very first HTTP request returning the page with the form and the dialog. It's merely hidden by CSS and is supposed to be shown/hidden by JS. When you change the confirm message afterwards in a bean action method, then it won't be reflected in the generated HTML output as long as you don't ajax-update it.

So, in order to get the changed message being reflected, you'd need to update the HTML representation of the `<p:confirmDialog>` in the client side before showing it in the `oncomplete`. You can for this use the `update` attribute of the command button which should show the dialog.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="confirmDialog testPlanetree">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this i should works :

```
<p:commandButton value="Delete" update="testPlanetree" id="deleteBtn" actionListener="#
         {projectTestManagementMB.testFn}"
       disabled="# {projectTestManagementMB.disable}" 

       oncomplete="deleteConfirmation.show()"  />
```

Comment: How exactly does this answer this question? You didn't explain/describe the solution concretely in any way. You've only shown a piece of code which is mostly similar to the OP's one with the only change being that you used `actionListener` instead of `action`. Why exactly do you think that this solves OP's concrete problem? Why exactly didn't you explain the solution in any way and do we have to guess it based on comparing the code? Whoever upvoted this unclear answer should resconsider the upvote.