# how to include data returned from a js function into a confirm dialog on the same page in jsf / primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying a message from managed bean with primefaces confirmation dialog component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568162/displaying-a-message-from-managed-bean-with-primefaces-confirmation-dialog-compo)

Setting: jsf 2 and primefaces.

My xhtml page includes a canvas with a graphic on it. The user can click on a region of the graphic, this calls a js function which returns a string specific to this region, let's call it "textFromClickedRegion". This string is stored in a inputHidden field.

The next line in the javascript submits the form containing the inputhidden field to a bean, and makes opens a confirmDialog (in primefaces), with a header which should be customized by the string from the bean.

Problem: the dialog opens, but the string never gets the value of bean (which is simply textFromClickedRegion).

The js script:

```
textFromClickedRegion = region.getText();
document.getElementById('formId:nameClicked').value = textFromClickedRegion;
document.getElementById('formId:submitNameClicked').click();
```

The xhtml:

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:inputHidden id="nameClicked" value="#{reportBean.nameClicked}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="submitNameClicked" type="button" process="@form" onclick="cd.show();"/>
</h:form>

<p:confirmDialog id ="dialogBox" message="#{reportBean.nameClicked}, are you sure about destroying the world?"
                         header="Initiating destroy process" severity="alert"
                         widgetVar="cd">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure" oncomplete="confirmation.hide();"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation.hide();" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

How can I get my confirmDialog to display the string returned by the js function?

[note: you will recognize that the above is a mix of the Primefaces manual and a [post by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) on the communication between client and server and jsf / js - thanks to him].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```java
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private String value;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        value = "SERVER SIDE VALUE";
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

```html
<h:head>
    <script>
        function updateElementValue(id,value){
            document.getElementById(id).value = value;
        }
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="form" prependId="false">

        <p:commandButton value="UPDATE CLIENT SIDE VALUE OF INPUT-HIDDEN"
                         onclick="updateElementValue('nameInputHiddenId',
                                                     'CLIENT SIDE VALUE');
                                                      return false;"/>
        <p:commandButton value="UPDATE SERVER SIDE VALUE OF INPUT-HIDDEN" 
                         process="@form" 
                         update="dialogId" 
                         oncomplete="dialogWidgetVar.show();" />

        <h:inputHidden id="nameInputHiddenId" value="#{bean.value}" />

        <p:dialog id="dialogId" widgetVar="dialogWidgetVar">
            <h:outputText id="nameOutputTextId" value="#{bean.value}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" onclick="dialogWidgetVar.hide();" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="dialogWidgetVar.hide();"/>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Comment: thx! Just tried it and I understand why it was missing. Still no update though?